# Is it possible to stop the Pi from powering the GPIO Ports 1,2 and 4?

Tags: power

As the title suggests, I would like to stop the Pi from providing power through the GPIO ports. Is this possible?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I was, as an example, thinking about an easy fan control, taking the power from the fan whenever the pi is cool enough.

Comment: On/Off fan control https://www.instructables.com/id/Control-a-Cooling-Fan-on-a-Raspberry-Pi-3/

Comment: I did know about solutions using a transistor but was curious if it would be possible without using one. But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Pins 1 and 17 are connected to the 3V3 rail.

Pins 2 and 4 are connected to the 5V rail.

They are not GPIO.

Comment: Ok, that's a point. This means it is impossible to make the pi not power these pins, right?